# Complex representation

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group of order $n$ and $\rho : G \to GL(V)$ is a complex representation with dimension $n$. Show that $p$ is irreducible.

This problem was on m prelim today and I wrote, "Since the groups has order a $n$ and $\rho$ has dimension $n$, the minimal polynomial is not reducible. Since $\rho$ is the minimal polynomial, $\rho$ is not reducible.

I feel like I was way off with my answer and was wondering what I was off about.

Comment: I think you've written the statement wrong...it's definitely not true as written.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the statement is incorrect as written. Even stronger actually, I claim that

> If $G$ is a finite group of order $n$, and $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ is a complex representation of dimension $n$, then $\rho$ is **not** irreducible.

To see why, note that $$|G|=\sum\limits_{V\text{ irrep}} \dim(V)^2$$ so unless $G$ is trivial, $\dim(V)$ cannot be $n$.